# HTML created by PHP is created out of sequence

Tags: php, html, fancybox

I have a PHP file which outputs some HTML.

For ease of configuration I have a `second` PHP file that is included in the `first` PHP file. This included file simply contains an array definition as follows:

```
<?
$myArray = array("key1"=>"value 1","key2"=>"value 2","key3"=>"value 3");
?>
```

In my first PHP file I have the following

```
<? include("second.php"); ?>

<label>Select here:
<select id='mySelect'>
<? foreach ($myArray as $keyString=>$valueString) { ?>
    <option value='<?= $keyString; ?>'><?= $valueString; ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
</label>
```

However the HTML output is generated as follows:

```
<label>Select here:
<select id='mySelect'>
</select>
<option value='key1'>value 1</option>
<option value='key2'>value 2</option>
<option value='key3'>value 3</option>
</label>
```

which renders as an empty select dropdown with the text of the options shown below it!

I'm sure this is something stupid and simple as I'm sure I have done this many times before without problems...

---

[Update]

After investigation it turns out that this is only happening when I display the `first` PHP page within FancyBox - when I load it directly the options are included in the `<select>` as you would expect.

The FancyBox is opened via JavaScript via the onClick event of an image as follows (the image is on the background page that the FancyBox opens on, it is not part of first.php or second.php):

```
<img src="myImage.png" alt="my image" onClick="openFirstPHP();">
```

in my JavaScript I have (in `first.js` which is included in `first.php` with the usual `<SCRIPT>` tags):

```
function openFirstPHP() {
    $.fancybox({
        href: "/first.php",
        type: "ajax",
        afterShow: function() {
            // do some setting of some radio buttons' states - which works fine
        }
    });
}
```

For info, the reason I call `first.php` this way rather than in an iFrame or whatever is that it interacts with the calling page as well and so avoid me having to reference a different document object (I think).

Basically everything else works without problems in `first.php` - the reading and settings of cookies, the interaction with the calling PHP page variables etc. The only thing that is not working is the insertion of these `<options>` tags out of sequence with the `<select>` tags.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: This is pretty impossible to happen :) All should work as expected. Do you use any complicated cache or special configuration? Is this a raw output or something that you see in the `console` of your browser? See test execution, it works fine in all php versions... https://3v4l.org/mHc2r

Comment: I agree.. that's why I'm so puzzled by it. This is what I am seeing in the browser and with the Firefox developer inspector. No complicated cache or config, and I do the same kind of thing in many other PHP scripts on the same server. Really puzzling me, this one.

Comment: Oooohkay.... maybe I've found something. This problem only happens when the `first` page is loaded into a fancyBox overlay - loading the page directly it works, so the fancyBox load process seems to be tripping things up...

Comment: @FatMonk This [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)? If that's the case, and the problem only happens with it, you should add the snippet you use to call it and the fancybox tag in the question. Edit: I don't see how it may be messing with the content.

Comment: @Theraot Will do, may not be right away though... I need to dig through my JScript stuff as FancyBox is called via a function...

Comment: @FatMonk I tested with fancyBox 2.1.4, it works as expected. I did also test with various versions of jQuery. Perhaps some other code is altering the DOM.

Comment: I'll investigate some more over the weekend.. its a puzzler...

Comment: OK. Pass me the stupid hat. My opening `<select>` statement had a stray / in it. i.e. `<select id='mySelect' />`. Because browsers do their best to make sense of malformed HTML, looking in the inspectors the `<select>` was followed by a `</select>` and then my options, and the closing `</select>` from my code was being dropped. Oddly, though, this only happened when called inside FancBox, when calling the page directly it worked without problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an odd one caused by a typo in my HTML markup rather than a problem with PHP or out-of-sequence markup generation.

My opening `<select>` statement had a stray / in it. i.e.

```
<select id='mySelect' />.
```

Because browsers do their best to make sense of malformed HTML, looking in the inspectors the `<select>` was immediately followed by a `</select>` then my options and the closing `</select>` from my code was being dropped entirely so the `<option>` statements were outside of the select and so being ignored.

Oddly, though, this only happened when called inside FancBoxy, when calling the page directly it worked without problems!

Removing the mis-placed / in the openeing `<select>` statement completely resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a `for` loop, but you treated it like a `foreach` loop.

This should work:

```
<? foreach ($myArray as $keyString=>$valueString) { ?>
    <option value='<?= $keyString; ?>'><?= $valueString; ?></option>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: The real question should be how OP got any output AT ALL. That code is flat-out syntax error and should have died with an `unexpected  'as' (T_AS)` fatal parse error

Comment: Sorry, that as a typo in the question.. it was, of course, a foreach...

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop from 'for' to 'foreach'.

Comment: that was a typo in question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php include_once("second.php");
 ?>

<label>Select here:
<select id='mySelect'>
<?php foreach ($myArray as $keyString=>$valueString) { ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $keyString; ?>'><?php echo $valueString; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</label>
```